# Node.js: Chain process.exit() calls

Tags: node.js

It would be neat if you could chain process.on('exit') calls like so

```
process.on('exit', function firstHandler(err,code,cb){  //this signature is fictitious for this example only
     if(condition){
        cb(null);   // this would call the next process.on('exit') listener
      }  
});

process.on('exit', function secondHandler(err,code,cb){
    //we really exit this time
});
```

is this functionality possible somehow? I know this goes against the way event emitters / listeners work, but the reason I ask the question is because I want to prevent an exit if there is a certain condition and then reinvoke `process.exit()` once the condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

It already works that way. By default, EventEmitters add event listeners when the `on()` method is called (default maximum is 10 listeners though you can change that). Since the `exit` event is implemente as a regular EventEmitter, you can add more than one listener by calling `on()` multiple times:

```
process.on('exit',function(){console.log('will exit')});
process.on('exit',function(){console.log('really, I will quit')});
process.on('exit',function(){console.log('DEAD')});
```

Output:

```
will exit
really, I will quit
DEAD
```

Note that the listeners will be called in the sequence they were added. See the documentation of Events for more info: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: yeah, but this doesn't yield the functionality I am looking for - I want to prevent an exit - think I just need to use an intermediate step before calling process.exit()

Answer (score 1):

You can't cancel an exit. [From the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit):

> Emitted when the process is about to exit. There is no way to prevent the exiting of the event loop at this point, and once all 'exit' listeners have finished running the process will exit.

Comment: however, you can cancel an exit if you listen for the 'beforeExit' event - https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: @AlexMills I don't see anything about cancellation, it only says you can do some more work before the end. Also, `beforeExit` is not triggered when the exit is explicit (process.exit() or an exception), it fires only when the program terminate normally (no more things to do).

Answer (score 0):

Once the "exit" event is emitted, you cannot prevent the node.js process from terminating.

*However*, if you listen for the "beforeExit" event, shown here:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

You can prevent the process / event loop from terminating by adding calls.